# Bluetooth not accessible from GUI

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I just installed Ubunu 22.04 and the bluetooth is not working from the GUI. I have no clue why and I have tried to look around for answers but cannot seem to find any that works.

When I run

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
```

I get that it is active and running but when I use

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
$ scan on
```

I get that "No default controller available".

I am a noob so please feel free to tell me which commands to run so that I can get to the bottom of this.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Adding terminal output as asked

```
$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; sudo  lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0170]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
03:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.104660] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.985814] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.985841] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.985842] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.985845] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.985848] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.985852] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.067362] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.067366] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.067368] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.067384] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.067385] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.067395] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.067420] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.067508] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    3.067520] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.067521] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    3.067530] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    3.132419] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro14,1.bin failed with error -2
[    3.133378] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro14,1.txt failed with error -2
[    3.133411] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    3.486341] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4350/5 wl0: Nov 26 2015 03:48:57 version 7.35.180.133 (r602372) FWID 01-c45b39d6
[    3.764364] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    4.234073] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.234077] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.234082] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.414820] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc18 tx timeout
[   13.602998] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: failed to write update baudrate (-110)
[   13.603019] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set baudrate
[   15.619029] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   23.842786] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
[   29.006304] audit: type=1107 audit(1682360106.986:60): pid=545 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=1849 label="snap.nordpass.nordpass" peer_pid=543 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31 thanks for your reply! I now updated the post with the output you asked for.